# JPEG Image from Serial Camera not loading with C# BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, jpeg

I am writing a program which grabs JPEG images from a camera which is connected via Serial Port. I want to programmatically define an image in WPF, in order to display it once it is retreived, using the Source attribute of Image.

I have found that

```
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/" + photo + ".jpg"));
```

Is working absolutely fine with most images, but for some reason it doesn't like the images from this camera. Can anyone who knows more than me about JPEG please take a look at it and see why it might be a problem?

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2434899/0%20%282%29.jpg

EDIT: After some investigation, I have determined that it is probably the JFIF header data that WPF/C# does not like. Is there any easy way to correct it in-program?

EDIT 2: I believe I have found the problem. The camera's JFIF header data is complete junk. It's basically just 0-10... Had to read it with a Hex editor in the end. I copied across the JFIF header from the working file and now it is fine. Just got to edit each header as it comes in, I guess.

For the information of anyone who encounters this problem with this camera:

http://www.4dsystems.com.au/prod.php?id=75

It seems to give out the same junk header information with each photo:

FF D8 FF E0 00 11 4A 46 49 46 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A FF DB

And none of it matches with anything in the JFIF standard:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format

It seems that if you just replace the JFIF header with this:

FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 FF DB

It will work. Just read the file up until the "FF DB" which is also in the junk header - it seems to be the 'stop word' for the header - and then swap out that for this.

There is a second lot of what would appear to be header information which continues on until byte 26E... and it seems to be the same in both of the images I have here, but it doesn't seem to be the cause of the C# loading issue. It doesn't look like anything in JFIF, so I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say, but I think this image is "corrupt." I think the image stream that save this image didn't close/dispose properly. I loaded the image in XAML and got the error:

Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F72

Then I opened the image in Paint/Photoshop and re-saved it. I opened the re-saved image in XAML and no error. It looks like Photoshop read it fine and when it saved it saved it correctly

Comment: Any tips on how to figure out in what way it is corrupt? I may know that it is bad, but I don't know whether it's my program or the camera that's the problem.

Comment: I did notice that after saving with Paint the image has doubled to 41KB instead of 20KB.

Comment: Open the image into a byte[] and remove the header. This is not what should be done. You should really fix the source (camera) if you can.

Comment: There's not really much I can do besides e-mailing the manufacturers... The problem will be with the JPEG Encoder IC that is on the PCB...

Comment: Oh, also. I have updated my OP with a solution of sorts... It'll have to do. At least this gives me something to put in my Dissertation.